# How do I keep a hover state active when mousing over another div with CSS only

Tags: html, css, hover

First of all, say that I tried to find an answer to my questions through the previous posts, but couldn't find anything that would fit my specific issue. Also mention that I am a beginner at this, just started learning last week, but I am very eager to learn.

That being said, I have the following question:

How do I make Logo1 (picture) stay with opacity 1.0 (its natural opacity is 0.5) after hovering onto option1 or option2 with CSS only? After I leave either Logo1, option1 or option2 it should go back to opacity 0.5.
Also mention that Option1 and Option2 appear when hovering over Logo1.

If it is something that can't be done, I accept some JavaScript, but I haven't started learning it yet.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInText {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeInText {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLogo {
    from { opacity: 0.5; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeInLogo {
    from { opacity: 0.5; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}

.container {
position:relative;
}

ul {
 list-style-type:none;
}

.logo1 {
 left:20px;
 top:30px;
 position:absolute;
 opacity:0.5;
}
 .linea1 {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 left:70px;
 top:50px;
}
.logo1:hover+.linea1,.linea1:hover {
 display:block;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInText 1.5s;
 animation: fadeInText 1.5s;
}
.logo1:hover{
 display:block;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInLogo 1.5s;
 animation: fadeInLogo 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="logo1">
    <img src="1.png">
</div>

<div class="linea1">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#option1">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#option2">Option2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gotta use Javascript.

Comment: Aww.... :( 
Ok thx.
Would it be easy to do?

Comment: JavaScript IS fun (I highly recommend it), but this can be done with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS. Put your `:hover` pseudo-class on the parent container:

```
.container:hover .linea1 {
  display:block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInText 1.5s;
  animation: fadeInText 1.5s;
}

.container:hover .logo1 {
  display:block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInLogo 1.5s;
  animation: fadeInLogo 1.5s;
}
```

But even better, would be to use `transition` instead of animation in this instance, because the transition state will remain so long as you're hovering. Animation is more useful when you have more then one keyframe.

```
.logo1 {
  left:20px;
  top:30px;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.5;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
}
.linea1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:70px;
  top:50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
}
.container:hover .linea1 {
  opacity: 1
}
.container:hover .logo1 {
  opacity: 1
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/eJdpWG?editors=110)

Comment: Wow thanks, that definitely helps, unfortunately I will have to change some html since this was just a part of the whole, but at least I know where to continue from here :)

Comment: It doesn't have to be `.container`. Just add another element that wraps your logo / options, and use that as your hover area.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was doing, I created a "minicontainer" for that logo1+options.